# ms access: how to format dlookup

Tags: ms-access

I have a textbox where I use dlookup funtion for showing value. The code is

```
=DLookUp("[Weightage]","[PreferenceMatrix1T]","[Index]='La2O3'")/100 & "%"
```

and it gives output as `6.3391442155309E-05%` but I want to show it like `6.34%`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Format property of the textbox to Percent and Decimals property to 2.